# Understanding C++ memory model : Different values on different runs

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, parallel-processing, atomic

What is wrong with the below code? I expect to see 10 to be produced by consumer1 and consumer2, but I see -1 sometimes.

```
#include <thread>   
#include <atomic>
#include <cassert>
#include <string>

std::atomic<int> global;
void producer()
{
   global.store(10, std::memory_order_release);
}

void consumer1()
{
   int a = global.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
   printf("a in consumer1 %d\n", a);
}

void consumer2()
{
   int a = global.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
   printf("a in consumer2 %d\n", a);
}

int main()
{
    global.store(-1, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    std::thread t1(producer);
    std::thread t2(consumer1);
    std::thread t3(consumer2);
    t1.join(); t2.join(); t3.join();
}
```

I see 
    `a in consumer1 10`
    `a in consumer2 10`
and
    `a in consumer1 -1`
    `a in consumer2 10`

If I understand correctly, the thread which does `memory_order_acquire` always syncs with the thread which does `memory_order_release`. Am I wrong?
I am running on x86-64 bit machine. I am compiling with
 g++ file.cpp -pthread -std=c++11

Comment: With your example, I never got -1, always "a in consumer1 10
a in consumer2 10" could you put some sleep to have the "wrong" result you post?

Comment: run for multiple times. I ran it for at least 20 times and amongst them one run showed -1.

Comment: I am over my 100 tests.

Comment: But I do see Here is the output directly pasted from my terminal.
 madhura@linux64  ~  ./a.out
a in consumer2 10
a in consumer1 10
 madhura@linux64  ~  ./a.out
a in consumer1 -1
a in consumer2 10

Comment: Which compiler/options do you use?

Comment: This is the hard part of working with parallel programs, I cannot easily prove that I see different values :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91692/discussion-between-username-4567-and-adrian-maire).

Comment: I wonder: You run three threads concurrently (maybe even in parallel), but how do you ensure execution order? Can you say which is the mutex in your example ?

Comment: I agree. That is what I was wondering. So, acquire-release doesn't necessarily impose ordering on execution right? So, why does C++ spec says "synchronizes with"?

Comment: "synchronizes with" means that **if** `global` has been updated by producer, the consumer will see the update. Possibly by forcing cache updates, or whatever is needed. It doesn't mean that if consumer runs ahead of producer, it will stop and wait.

Comment: If you want task A to be done strictly before task B, it's easiest to do them on a single thread. Having thread 1 run to completion and only then start thread 2 to continue calculation is just inefficient.

Answer (score 4):

Atomic variables have the very nice property that the value read is a value that has been written before. And with release/acquire semantics it's even the *last* value written.

In this case, you have 2 writes and two reads. Only the write of -1 is sequenced-before the reads, the write of 10 is not sequenced. Therefore either value may be the last written. It's guaranteed that you read -1 or 10 and not garbage.

Comment: "Only the write of -1 is sequenced-before the reads, the write of 10 is not sequenced" I did not get this, What do you mean by term Sequence-before?

Comment: @username_4567: That's how C++11 defines the order of execution in mult-threaded programs. If two operations are sequenced relative to each other, the one that's sequenced-before will certainly happen first. Unsequenced operations can happen in any order, possibly simultaneous.

Answer (score 3):

If you add a sleep before

```
global.store(10, std::memory_order_release);
```

then you can observe consistently a -1.

The key point is that std::memory_order is not a sempaphore-like syncronization, but a rather more subtle matter. See [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)